# No mapping for LONGVARCHAR in Hibernate 3.2

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, jdbc

I am running Hibernate 3.2.0 with MySQL 5.1.  After updating the group_concat_max_len in MySQL (because of a group_concat query that was exceeding the default value), I got the following exception when executing a SQLQuery with a group_concat clause:

"No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1"

-1 is the java.sql.Types value for LONGVARCHAR.  Evidently, increasing the group_concat_max_len value causes calls to group_concat to return a LONGVARCHAR value.  This appears to be an instance of this bug:

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3892

I guess there is a fix for this issue in Hibernate 3.5, but that is still a development version, so I am hesitant to put it into production, and don't know if it would cause issues for other parts of my code base.  I could also just use JDBC queries, but then I have to replace every instance of a SQLQuery with a group_concat clause.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, two suggestions. Either:

1. Patch Hibernate 3.2.0 with the changes of [HHH-3892](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3892?page=com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin%3Afisheye-issuepanel) i.e. get Hibernate sources, apply the patches for [r16501](http://fisheye.jboss.org/changelog/Hibernate?cs=16501), [r16823](http://fisheye.jboss.org/changelog/Hibernate?cs=16823) and [r17332](http://fisheye.jboss.org/changelog/Hibernate?cs=17332)) and build Hibernate yourself.
2. Or use a custom dialect as suggested in [HHH-1483](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1483):

   ```
   public class MySQL5Dialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect {
       public MySQL5Dialect() {
           super();
           // register additional hibernate types for default use in scalar sqlquery type auto detection
           // http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1483
           registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, Hibernate.TEXT.getName());
       }    
   }
   ```

Option #2 is easy to implement and to test (I didn't) while option #1 is "cleaner" but require (a bit) more work. Personally, I'd choose option #1 because that's what you will get with 3.5 and thus guarantees a seamless upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal's answer sounds very good, but I took a shortcut, for now.

Calling addScalar for every query return value also alleviates this problem.  As it turns out, there were not very many places in my code with a group_concat but no explicit calls to addScalar.  Adding these makes the issue go away.  (Note that you must have a call to addScalar for every return value, not just those coming from a group_concat.)

Comment: +1 thanks for this, I was using a group_concat in my query and using addScalar on all of my return values cleared up the issue.

Comment: Hi...do you have any idea 'why' this alleviates the issue?