# How to resolve “No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1” error in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

i'm getting **No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1** error.
Previously i asked same question but i'm not catch correct solution.So again i'm asking.

How to resolve this error i.e,

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:393)
```

my code here:

```
Session session = null;
session =  getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query qu = session.createSQLQuery("select xml from details " +
        "where start_date between (select * from(select eventdate from emplyoeevent " +
        "where event='logout' and event_id in (select session_id from session " +
        "where session_emplyoee='"+Id+"') order by eventdate asc) " +
        "where rownum=1) and TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')");
List li =  qu.list();
```

I'm getting error in List li =  qu.list(); line. What is the meaning of this error.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Post the code in your **`hibernate.cfg.xml`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to retrieve individual columns rather than entities, you may specify that with `addScalar`.

The following example assumes that `xml` is a String type, you may change it to fit the real type.

```
qu = qu.addScalar("xml", StringType.INSTANCE);
List li = qu.list();
```

JDBC Type `-1` is [LONGVARCHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#LONGVARCHAR), and is the type that is supposed to be returned by your query.

Depending on the version, Hibernate may not support this, see : [No mapping for LONGVARCHAR in Hibernate 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326935/no-mapping-for-longvarchar-in-hibernate-3-2) .

Hence, you have to specify the type yourself as in the above example.

Comment: :qu = **qu.addScalar("xml", StringType.INSTANCE);** where tio change your code i mean entire change my query or after query replace your code

Comment: Just add this line before "List li =  qu.list();", and keep the rest of your code as it is .

Comment: I added same way but it shows error in **INSTANCE** and i also addedd **import org.hibernate.type.StringType;**